# OAuth signature validation failed

Tags: java, oauth, jersey

I'm trying to get my web application to accept OAuth 1.0 requests from Instructure's canvas application.  The canvas setup is pretty simple, you configure an external application by providing a URL, Consumer Key, Shared Secret and any additional custom fields.  On my end I accept the call through a Java Servlet page and pass it to a Jersey library to verify the signature but it always fails validation.  My application has successfully accepted OAuth requests from the Moodle LMS and I've tested my site using the http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php site.  What has me further scratching my head is that the term.ie site has a server test as well and when I configure the canvas app to launch that I get a successful response.  I've been trying to go through their source code to get an idea of how the generate a signature and it appears that they take all parameters into account.  On my end I'm feeding the jersey oauth library the entire request.

Any ideas on things I could double check or try?  I've double checked the Consumer/Shared key, tried new ones and made sure the time is in sync as well.

Comment: it would be helpful if you'd share more details of your implementation e.g. the relevant Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at several OAuth examples  I noticed that the way we were calling our application within Canvas was causing us to add an additional parameter that was not included in the signature calculation.  I modified our end to not need the parameter and the signatures started to match.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, could you say what is the parameter? Thanks